# WordPress Plugins Development: How to initialize database when Plugin insalled/activated, and delete database when Plugin deactivated/deleted

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins, widget, initialization

I have a question:

How to initialize database when Plugin insalled/activated, 
and delete database when Plugin deactivated/deleted.

The platform is PHP+MySQL on WAMP.

Can ANYONE help me?

Really Appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

**Crete MySQL table while installing plugin**

Simply execute your MySQL create query in your plugin main file.While executing create query simply check this table is already exist or not.

**Drop Mysql table while uninstalling plugin**

Use [register_uninstall_hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook) function(To answer this part of question  [Rarst](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/847/rarst) helped me ).

More details [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25910/uninstall-activate-deactivate-a-plugin-typical-features-how-to/25979#25979)